Gym. make() error: TypeError: 'module' object is not callable， but gym has been imported correctly and there are no duplicate files
As the title suggests, an error for gym.make(): TypeError: 'module' object is not measurable, but the project name and other paths do not include gym (i.e. there is no file name conflict with gym library). At the same time, the  function variables under the qym function in the monitoring bar reported an error: make=SyntaxError ('invalid syntax, '', 1,1.<function make at 0x0000011466B88CA0>'), Why is this? How did this happen？
The editor is VScode, the Python version is 3.9.7, and the gym library version is 0.21.0. Despite trying the following methods, the issue still persists: changing the project file name (all in lowercase), checking the spelling and indentation of all variables in the code, and installing gym version 0.20.0
